# Why can't I use my dll that is referenced config file

Tags: c#, winforms, class, app-config

I would like to ask this question it is crazy that inside the dll code I can't reference the `dll.config` file and its only compiled into the exe and copied to any other project to the solution.

Haven't you ever wondered when you created a dll file (`DataAccess.dll`) for instance which you would like to use for different applications with different sql connection strings but when you build the solution it creates a `DataAccess.dll.config` file but never copies it into any other solution that is of either a Winforms or Windows service. It just stays there.

If your try to copy the config file over and change the values, you only get what was originally compiled at the time even thought it looks like in the dll your accessing the config settings with intellisense, the values are ignored after compilation. If you open your dll in notepad you will see your settings are compiled into the dll itself.

It boggles my mind that I would have to copy the values from the config file manually into the exe's config file to access configuration settings in an object oriented intellisense manager, except I have to use a hard coded open config file by path and search threw elements

What is the deal? No answer for what to me seams what would be a much easier way of doing things, let alone realistic and by design

Comment: That's just the way the .NET team decided to do it's configuration system - c'est la vie - get over it, and get on with your life.....

Answer (score 5):

A `dll` does not have an associated config file in .NET.

Why? Because a `dll` is not stand alone - it runs in the context of an executable.

The config that will be read is the one associated with the executable.

You need to change the `.exe.config` file in order for the configuration values to be updated.

Comment: why couldnt microsoft just copy the settings into the config file instead of me copy and pasting the files

Comment: @user1179388 - that, you should ask Microsoft, not SO. It is the way they have decided to do it.

Comment: i dont have an MSDN or a chance to,  Oded do you really think my point is valid and should be brought up and to what address or contact?

Comment: @user1179388 - I think that it is much too late to change. And I don't agree with your point of view - since a DLL is only running in the context of an EXE, it makes sense that the configuration would be tied to an EXE. You can always raise an issue on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/) for the .NET platform.

Comment: so the answer is thi http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/accessappconfigfromdll.html